# Eclipse Will Not Recognize Quotation Marks?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

This was my code:

```
<android:id="@+id/carrotsmileanim></android:id>
```

I fixed it because it was missing a quotation mark, but now eclipse won't recognize the quotations nor the "@" sign. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: That is not valid XML. An XML tag has a *tag* and *attributes*. Here, you have combined the two. You've made a *tagribute*!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you trying to do? That's not the way you declare IDs... this is how it works:

```
<Element android:id="@+id/carrotsmileanim">  </Element>
```

Notice that *Element* is usually a `View` (`TextView`, `Button`, etc.)

Comment: @Mia: just do it that way and your life will become wonderful.